# Trouble adding a variable as a table name SQL/PHP

Tags: c#, php, sql, database

I am having some issues with my code. It has worked previously, but now it seems to not want to work at all.

The PHP line is as follows: (all sensitive data has been altered for protective purposes)

```
<?php
$servername = "*****";
$server_username = "*****";
$server_password = "*****";
$dbName = "*****";

$tableName = $_POST["tableNamePost"];
$variable1 = $_POST["variable1Post"];
$variable2 = $_POST["variable2Post"];
$variable3 = $_POST["variable3Post"];
$variable4 = $_POST["variable4Post"];
$variable5 = $_POST["variable5Post"];

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $server_username, $server_password, $dbName);

if(!$conn)
{
    die("Connection Failed" .mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$tableName." VALUES ('".$variable1."', '".$variable2."', '".$variable3."', '".$variable4."', '".$variable5."', '0', '0', '0', '0')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
```

All variables for tableName(s) are matching as they are static variables in the program itself. The C# code segment is as follows: (again, all sensitive data has been altered for protective purposes)

```
public string tableName;
public int var1;
public string var2;
public string var3;
public string var4;
public int var5;
public float var6;
public float var7;
string AddToTableURL = "http://urlofthe.php"; //The actual link has been tested and works fine.

public void FunctionInQuestion()
{
    float i = (var7 / 60.0f * var6);
    var5 = Mathf.FloorToInt(i);
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("tableNamePost", tableName);
    form.AddField("dayNumberPost", var1.ToString());
    form.AddField("dueDayPost", var2);
    form.AddField("timeOfTheDayPost", var3);
    form.AddField("choreNamePost", var4);
    form.AddField("pointsOnOfferPost", var5.ToString());
    WWW www = new WWW(AddToTableURL, form);
    NextFunction();
}
```

The problem I am having is that my C# that defines the variables is running through correctly, but I cannot determine as to whether the PHP is receiving the variables or not. Every time I run the scripts, nothing is added to the databases.

Has something been missed or is incorrectly written? I have been over the code for a few days now and cannot find the issue.

Comment: Show more of the code, this tells us very little

Comment: Love to know who thinks this is a _well researched useful and clear questions_?

Comment: Why is this tagged `C#`?

Comment: C# has been added automatically. I am unsure as to why.
The full PHP will be edited into the question. Can't trust employees -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to make debug-purpose PHP code to check what's going on, or to read PHP error and database server error logs if enabled on the server.

As far as I see from this code we have: tableName (C#) as null.

Also, depending on version of MySQL server you're running it might be issue of not putting the table name in the right quote symbol - try qouting `$tableName` like this on PHP side.

Also, check the character-set you're using for database connection - if $tableName has some Unicode characters or something?

And just in case make full database.tablename path in INSERT INTO call - maybe you're selecting another database in other places on the PHP side.

The last thing I would double check: are you sure you want to insert these zeros as varchar/text value and not as integer? Remove the quotes around them.

---

**Update 1:** 
Are you sure you are using HTTP POST method with the form (C#)?
I can't see in your code your're setting POST as method of the WWW form object.

**Update 2:**
Put **mysqli** debug code to see if there were also errors in the SQL execution/syntax.

Check this example from PHP documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if (!$mysqli->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test") ||
    !$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE test(id INT)") ||
    !$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (1)")) {
    echo "Table creation failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
?>
```

Try this form of the INSERT INTO command.

Comment: Not sure I understand you, tableName is set elsewhere in the code, that is just the section relevant to this error. I have made the changes as you have suggested (although I cannot find the correct PHP for debugging, so not that bit) and nothing has solved the issue.

And yes, the zeros are VARCHAR not INT, I have made the entire table VARCHAR for simplicity for the other programmers.

Comment: I have checked the php_error_log and when I forced an error I got an error of
`[04-Jul-2017 07:36:45 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: tableNamePost in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/pointspal/addchoretotable.php on line ` for lines 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, and 12.
But when I use the program, no error occurs.

Comment: Well, the error tells you that C# sent no POST value under "tableNamePost" key, so, you might go back to C# to see where is the problem.

I suggest you temporally make a version of PHP code where you read GET parameters instead of POST so you are able manually to test only php-side of the problem. I do like that in similar situations. Once you are sure that PHP works properly - it will be much easier to handle the C# issue.

Comment: Also, you should start using isset() php command to verify POST/GET inputs before processing. It's very useful command, use like: if (isset($_POST["tableNamePost"])) { } to evaluate each key/value you expect. But, in this particular case we already know the "tableNamePost" is not set within $_POST

Comment: I think my concatenation is wrong with the tableName variable. I will add an image in a link to show the issue. [images](http://imgur.com/a/geqei) As you can see in that image, the top line is with concatenation, the bottom is a solid name and the VALUES on both lines is different.

Comment: No, it is ok to write like you have in the question. It is not the simplest form possible but I prefer to do like you done. The simplest form would be:
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tableName VALUES ("... 
So, without closing quotation and concatenation, but concentration is ok too - I value such way as more readable.

How ever - string concatenation is not your problem. Your problem is that $_POST["tableNamePost"] was never received or never sent - since the error says it is not defined ("Undefined index").

Comment: I think you should put temporally this line:
`print_r($_POST);`

at beginning of the PHP script.
It will print out all fields that were received via POST HTTP request. 
The output you have to catch on C# I assume, and print it to Console.WriteLine(); to see it.

Comment: Thank's mate, that worked perfectly to solve my issues. There was an error with the post, it has now been resolved. Thank's again.